# Processed data different than raw data on Firefox

Tags: json, firefox

I came across this strange issue when using tools to prettify JSON on Firefox 65. This is my object :

`{"status": 0, "message": "ok", "data": [466933532930080768, 537281936222191637]}`

And as expected values are correct in RAW :

[image: correct data]

But when using the JSON or Pretty Print tools, it is not :

[image: wrong data]

I tried a bunch of different JSON prettifier/formatter/validator and my object seems to be correct.

Am I missing something or did I just discovered a bug ?

Comment: no i'm sorry but in googlechrome is same

Comment: see this: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/bigint

Comment: for esample if you use Number("466933532930080768") the problem is a same, I think it was a problem with the JS engine, I had already heard of a similar problem for this type of pown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok your problem is famuos,

for fix this one you can pass string with your number and after you can use

```
BigInt("466933532930080768") // --> 466933532930080768n
```

for tacke a correct number.

do not worry about the final n JS treats it exactly like a number.

[Doc](http://2ality.com/2012/07/large-integers.html)

it also explains why and where does the error js